# Jest error with <Trans>: You forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: jestjs, react-i18next

> Error: Uncaught [Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
> component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
> default and named imports.

This is the error I was getting while running test in jest. React component which is being tested uses `<Trans>` from `react-i18next`. When I comment that portion of code, test were working as expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error shown is very very very miss leading.

In my case it was missing mock for `<Trans>`. While I had mock for `react-i18next`, but since I had many components to cover with tests, and some of them were using `<Trans>` and some of them not, I copy/paste test files but totally forgot to check about mock. It took me few hours to notice it, after I replaced `<Trans>` to text like `<Typography>` from material-ui...

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  withTranslation: () => (Component: any) => {
    Component.defaultProps = {...Component.defaultProps, t: (children: any) => children};
    return Component;
  },
  Trans: ({children}: any) => children, // this line was missing (() => jest.fn() might also work)
}));
```

Hope it will save some time for some of you :)

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own - you'll end up with a more and more complicated mock for react-i18next`, then if their API changes your code will break but your tests will *continue to pass*.

Comment: you are suggesting I shall utilize API for mock from their package? Didn't know there is something like it. Is that practice for most other npm packages which are used in React components?

Comment: I don't know if they have one; my point was more to test the overall *behaviour*, in this case presumably that some *translated* text is displayed by whatever component you were testing.

Comment: i am not sure i follow you. In our component we use withTranslation HoC to inject namespace and we inject t Function as props via WithTranslation.I think if we don't mock the package we have problems with tests.

Comment: I think you have the right idea here. Reason being that the react-i18next library expects you to create your own mocks. The part about mocking Trans is missing in their documentation, but something similar is there for useTranslation/withTranslation. https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, in order to resolve the issue I mocked the Trans component like this

```
  jest.mock("react-i18next", () => ({
       Trans: ({ i18nKey }: { i18nKey: string }) => i18nKey,
  }));
```

Instead of passing the node, we can simply pass the i18nKey.
In my case, I am only checking the key value. Hope it helps!